# Изменить состояние видимости файлов под гитом

Tags: git, intellij-idea

После того как был сделан `git clone`, все файлы после открытия проекта в **intellije idea**, отображались как unresolved(красный цвет). Добавил в конфигурационном файле гита, config линию с `worktree=/*path to project`, переключился на другую ветку. Все файлы изменили видимость с unresolved на new (синий цвет).

Update projecta пишет все файлы обновлены,я попробовал сделать **revert** файла и он изменил зону видимости с new на обычный тип файла(белый цвет).

Думаю применять `revert` для всех файлов не самое хорошее решение.
Что сделать чтобы все файлы были под нормальной видимостью гита, не (new, changed, unresolved)?

Comment: Ну, это видимо проблема Idea. Что говорит `git status`?

Comment: что все файлы 'modified'

Comment: Т.е. Вы ничего не меняли в файлах, а они помечены как изменённые и Вы хотите добиться того, чтобы все файлы стали не измененные, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @ixSci может это из-за окончаний строк? Автор, а что показывает `git diff`?

Answer (score 4):

Совсем неясно откуда взялись локальные изменения, если Вы ничего не меняли. Но, чтобы убрать все локальные изменения и вернуть их в то состояние, в котором они находятся в репозитории, Вы можете выполнить следующую команду:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Но будьте внимательны, если Вы сделали какие-то важные изменения и не зафиксировали их, то они тоже пропадут.

---

Также рекомендую ознакомится с [этим](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009096/files-showing-as-modified-directly-after-git-clone) вопросом на английской части SO, там рассматриваются различные варианты, почему после `git clone` могут появиться модифицированные файлы.

Comment: Почитайте решение автора. Как вам `worktree = / ` ? ))

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я, честно говоря, даже не знаю что это :)

Comment: Если я правильно понял документацию, то это глобальный конфиг, который говорит "рабочая область любого проекта находится в `/`".

Answer (score 0):

После удаления сроки `worktree = /` в global confige gita, проект после клона стал отображаться корректно, возможно решение @ixSci правильное, и

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

помогло бы.